# Re-arrange a list of objects with a criteria on a property (not ascending/descending)

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of objects(say Office object) which has properties like say id, name, location, strength. Now, suppose, the field location has values from a certain set (say 3 possible values, New York, California, Utah). Now, I want to re-arrange this list on the location property in a way that the Office object with location property as New York comes first in the list, followed by ones in California followed by Utah. So, basically it's not an ascending or descending order but a criteria set by me for that property. what would be the most efficient way to implement this in Java?

I first thought of using Comprator but I do not want to simply sort in an ascending/descending order but on the criteria I specify as mentioned above. Not sure, if i could use COmparator for this as well and if yes how. And, if not, then what is the other most efficient way?

Comment: `Collections.sort` can have an  additional Comparator of which you can make several, or on the fly. Java 8 allows  a very compact notation, and even combining comparators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, can't exclude and ideally need to contain all locations:

```
public static void rearrangeSort(List<Office> source, String... locations) {
    List<String> locs = Arrays.asList(locations);
    Collections.sort(source, (o1, o2) -> locs.indexOf(o1.getLocation()) - locs.indexOf(o2.getLocation()));
}
```

More complex:

```
public static List<Office> rearrange(List<Office> source, String... locations) {
    Map<String, List<Office>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Office office : source) {
        List<Office> lst = map.get(office.getLocation());
        if (lst == null) {
            lst = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(office.getLocation(), lst);
        }
        lst.add(office);
    }
    List<Office> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String loc : locations) {
        List<Office> partial = map.get(loc);
        if (partial != null) {
            resultList.addAll(partial);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Previous variant with lambdas:

```
public static List<Office> rearrange2(List<Office> source, String... locations) {
    Map<String, List<Office>> map = source.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Office::getLocation,
            o -> {List<Office> lst = new ArrayList<>(); lst.add(o); return lst;},
            (offices, offices2) -> {offices.addAll(offices2); return offices;}));
    return Arrays.asList(locations).stream()
            .filter(map::containsKey)
            .map(map::get)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I was looking at your first approach but apparantly it uses lambda expressions not allowed in Java 1.7 and below. I use 1.7

Comment: @user1892775 replace lambda with: new Comparator<Office>() { public int compare(Office o1, Office o2) { return locs.indexOf(o1.getLocation()) - locs.indexOf(o2.getLocation(); }}